# Delete docker image from remote repo

Tags: image, docker, remote-server

I have the following

docker registry :http://myPrivateRegistry:5000

repository : myRepo

Image : myImage

I pushed this image to the remote repo by the following

```
docker push http://myPrivateRegistry:5000/myRepo/myImage
```

How do I delete this image from the 'remote repo' not just locally?? 
`docker rmi http://myPrivateRegistry:5000/myRepo/myImage` untags the image but does not remove it from teh remote repo

Comment: September 2020 way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63833569

Answer (score 2):

After some time googling I've found that you could use Curl command to delete images, e.g:

```
curl -X DELETE registry-url/v1/repositories/repository-name/
```

Comment: This gives a message .. you should be redirected automatically to target URL: <a href="http://///myPrivateRegistry:5000/myRepo/myImage">http:////myPrivateRegistry:5000/myRepo/myImage/</a>.  If not click the link.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, this is still being debated in [issue 422](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/422)

> While deletes are part of the API, they cannot be safely implemented on top of an eventually consistent backend (read: s3).
>
> The main blocker comes from the complexity of reference counting on top of an eventually consistent storage system.
>   We need to consider whether it is worth facing that complexity or to adopt a hybrid storage model, where references are stored consistently.
>
> As long as the registry supports varied backends, using an eventually consistent VFS model, safe deletions are not really possible without more infrastructure.

[Issue 210](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/210) does mention

> Soft delete have been implemented as part of the API, and more specialized issues have been opened for garbage collection.

https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/422#issuecomment-114963170