# How to delete a repo from Docker Hub

Tags: docker, repository, dockerhub

How do I delete a repository from Docker Hub entirely?

Docker is evolving fast and so is their website. Here is the latest route to deleting your repo from docker hub web interface.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Firstly, make sure you are logged into hub.docker.com

### Simple

1. Click Repositories link (on blue menu bar) on top
2. Click the name of repo to be deleted
3. Click Settings link (on white sub menu bar)
4. Click the 'Delete repository' button
5. In the confirmation dialog box, type the name of your repo to reconfirm
6. Click Delete

### Detailed

1. Click "Repositories" link on top menu bar*
   [image]
2. Click on the repo you want to remove
   [image]
3. Click "Settings" sub-menu
   [image]
4. Decide from making it private or to delete and take action.
   [image]
5. Type the name of the repo to reconfirm
   [image]
6. When you have written the name of the repo, delete button would get enabled. Click it to delete your repo.

Comment: I could not see the field where to type, and the last picture here helped me to find it. bad design